# Custom Authorization/Authentication with Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, repository-pattern, membership

All greetings
Anyone can do their implementation Authorization system?
Do not use the Membership API?

Of course we could implement custom providers to plug a different database into this framework, as detailed at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx), but if my application is going to use a repository pattern for data access, and I’m going to have specific controllers and views for creating/editing users, why should membership and authorization be routed through this other framework?

If yes:
I'm just interested in how not to make holes in security.
Use FormsAuthenticationTicket?
How about IPrincipal?

Maybe you have some example or project on codeplex.com on other Authorization/Authentication

Answer (score 2):

**I use Kristoffer Ahl's excellent FluentSecurity library to manage authorization in a centralized place in my ASP.NET MVC applications.** The thing I like most about it is that it keeps me from forgetting to secure controllers because it throws an Exception when a Controller is accessed for which there is no security policy specified.

---

Resources:

- **Project Website:** [www.fluentsecurity.net](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/)
- **NuGet Package:** *install-package FluentSecurity* (see [NuGet Gallery](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/FluentSecurity))
- **Source Code:** [GitHub » kristofferahl » FluentSecurity](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity)